# .NET Maui Apple CarPlay custom UI

Tags: .net, maui, carplay

I am fully interested in writing .NET Maui Apple CarPlay application. I have found very useful tutorial here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yg2I6NbHZp8
but I would like to achieve interface like this:
[image]

Example of interface is taken from Apple https://developers.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/technologies/carplay/introduction

Unfortunately I do not have any idea how to do that in .net MAUI.
Thanks for any advices.

Comment: UPDATE! Found native solution here https://fotidim.com/automaker-carplay-apps-without-apples-or-automaker-s-blessings-3d7b9618923d but do not know how to translate it to MAUI.